# Объясните как сделать анимированные caption для слайдера

Tags: javascript

Привет! Как сделать аниммированые caption для слайдера как у слайдера revolution slider, ну или как подключить его без wordpress. Если не понятен вопрос то вот пример таких слайдеров http://themexlab.com/ самый первый слайдер - дата, заголовок и счетчик за друг другом всплывают

Comment: Укажите в вопросе с чем  конкретно у вас возникли проблемы?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.